# Problem installing texlive 2020 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: installing, texlive-2020

I'm trying to install texlive 2020 on ubuntu 18.04 using the command `perl install-tl`
I'm getting this error message,

```
Unknown regexp modifier "/b" at install-tl line 1, at end of line
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at install-tl line 32.
```

which is very odd since `install-tl` does not have any line in which "/b" appears.
Here are the first few lines of `install-tl`.

Could somebody advise please?

```
!/usr/bin/env perl
# $Id: texlive2020-20200406.iso,v 1.1 2020/05/17 18:09:10 simon Exp simon $
# Copyright 2007-2020
# Reinhard Kotucha, Norbert Preining, Karl Berry, Siep Kroonenberg.
# This file is licensed under the GNU General Public License version 2
# or any later version.
#
# Be careful when changing wording: *every* normal informational message
# output here must be recognized by the long grep in tl-update-tlnet.
```

This is the version of perl I'm running

```
This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 1 (v5.26.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
```

Comment: The first line does contain `/b`. (I have no idea how to start the installer on ubuntu, I'm on windows):

Comment: the command is sudo apt-get install texlive, or in the store (or package manager synaptic) search for texlive lybraries or the texlive-base, and the latex editors

Comment: Using `apt` would be wonderful if it worked, but for some reason `sudo apt-get install texlive` installs the 2017 version.  Unfortunately,  I need 2019 at least, which appears to be the latest version compatible with ubuntu 18.04.    Is there a way of making convincing `apt` to install the latest version?

Comment: you are missing a `#` on the first line

Comment: how did you obtain this script  (you should not get a corrupted first line if obtaining it from the standard sources)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However you obtained this install script it is corrupted.

```
!/usr/bin/env perl
```

should be

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

which specifies the interpreter to use on this script.

You are seeing it interpreted as `/usr/b` which is the regular expression  `/usr/` with the (bad) modifier `b`

Comment: Wierd, it was indeed corrupted.  Rather disturbing.  I downloaded another version and it ran  fine!   Thanks