# 2018 version of paralist.sty throws error but not 2019 version

Tags: spacing, enumerate, texlive-2019, texlive-2018

I'm running texlive 2018 on ubuntu 18.04.     To defeat `beamer`'s infuriating refusal to allow users to remove spaces before and after lists, I've created my own list environment, using `paralist`.     This runs fine on texlive 2019 but on texlive 2018 it throws this error:  `! Undefined control sequence. l.12 \if@plnewenum`.   The obvious solution is to update to 2019, but as I've explained in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577089/problem-installing-texlive-2020-on-ubuntu-18-04), the recommended procedure for updating doesn't work for me.      Is there a way to address the `paralist` error?      If not, is there an alternative way to achieve the same effect, i.e., no spaces above and below the list, eg:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{paralist}
    \newenvironment{beamerEnum}{
        \parskip=0pt
        \parindent=0pt
        \begin{compactenum}}
        {\end{compactenum}
    \parskip=12 pt plus 0 pt minus 0 pt}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{}
    Before the list
    \begin{beamerEnum}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \end{beamerEnum}
    After the list
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: texlive 2018 and 2019 cannot be updated via standard mechanisms. You should install texlive 2020 only the current texlive can be updated via `tlmgr`

Comment: the document runs without error in texlive 2016,2017,219 and 2020, in texlive 2018 I get `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix`

Comment: Maybe thid helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/569780/38080